How to select first N number of groups based on values of a column conditionally and groupby two columns?
This is a follow up to this post
This is my DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 10, 22],
        'b': [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
        'c': [25, 25, 25, 45, 45, 45, 45, 65, 65, 65, 65, 40, 40, 30, 30],
        'main': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']
    }
)

Expected output: Groupby main AND c:
    a  b   c main
0   10  1  25    x
1   15  1  25    x
2   20  1  25    x
3   25 -1  45    x
4   30 -1  45    x
5   35 -1  45    x
6   40 -1  45    x
11  65 -1  40    y
12  70 -1  40    y
13  10 -1  30    y
14  22 -1  30    y

The process is as follows: Note that groupby is done by TWO columns:
So for each main:
a) Selecting the group that all of the b values is 1. In my data and this df there is only one group with this condition.
b) Selecting first two groups (from top of df) that all of their b values are -1.
Note that there is a possibility in my data that there are no groups that has a or b condition. If that is the case, returning whatever matches the criteria is fine. For example the output could be only one group or no groups at all.
The groups that I want are shown below:

This is my attempt based on this answer but it appears that something else must change:
# identify groups with all 1
m1 = df['b'].eq(1).groupby(df['c', 'main']).transform('all')
# identify groups with all -1
m2 = df['b'].eq(-1).groupby(df['c', 'main']).transform('all')
# keep rows of first 2 groups with all -1
m3 = df[['c', 'main']].isin(df.loc[m2, ['c', 'main']].unique()[:2])

# select m1 OR m3
out = df[m1 | m3]


are the "c" unique or could they happen in two different groups?

both c and main are unique @mozway

So you can rely on "c" without needing to also check "main"

@mozway yes but how you gonna check if it is the first two goups of main? If you can then yes it is ok

@mozway Oh yes you can , superstar :)

You can update the previous code to get the first 2 unique "c" per main:
groups = [df['c'], df['main']]
# identify groups with all 1
m1 = df['b'].eq(1).groupby(groups).transform('all')
# identify groups with all -1
m2 = df['b'].eq(-1).groupby(groups).transform('all')
# keep rows of first 2 groups with all -1, per main
keep = set.union(*df.loc[m2, ['c', 'main']].groupby('main')['c']
                    .agg(lambda x: set(x.unique()[:2])))
# {25}
m3 = df['c'].isin(keep)

# select m1 OR m3
out = df[m1 | m3]

Or using a merge, but this won't necessarily keep the original order of the rows:
groups = [df['c'], df['main']]
# identify groups with all 1
m1 = df['b'].eq(1).groupby(groups).transform('all')
# identify groups with all -1
m2 = df['b'].eq(-1).groupby(groups).transform('all')
# keep rows of first 2 groups with all -1, per main
ref = df.loc[m2, ['c', 'main']].drop_duplicates().groupby('main').head(2)

out = pd.concat([df[m1], df.merge(ref)], ignore_index=True)

Output:
     a  b   c main
0   10  1  25    x
1   15  1  25    x
2   20  1  25    x
3   25 -1  45    x
4   30 -1  45    x
5   35 -1  45    x
6   40 -1  45    x
11  65 -1  40    y
12  70 -1  40    y
13  10 -1  30    y
14  22 -1  30    y


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 10, 22],
        'b': [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
        'c': [25, 25, 25, 45, 45, 45, 45, 65, 65, 65, 65, 40, 40, 30, 30],
        'main': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']
    }
)
print(df)

all_one_mask = df.groupby(['main','c'])['b'].transform(lambda x : (x == 1).all())
all_one = df[all_one_mask]
print(all_one)


all_minusone_mask = df.groupby(['main','c'])['b'].transform(lambda x : (x == -1).all())
all_minusone = df[all_minusone_mask]
print(all_minusone)

res = pd.concat([all_one,all_minusone],ignore_index = True)
print(res)
"""
     a  b   c main
0   10  1  25    x
1   15  1  25    x
2   20  1  25    x
3   25 -1  45    x
4   30 -1  45    x
5   35 -1  45    x
6   40 -1  45    x
7   65 -1  40    y
8   70 -1  40    y
9   10 -1  30    y
10  22 -1  30    y
"""

